# How do I call a name range using a cell reference?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to call a Named Range in a Google Sheets Query.

The name range is called Jazz_It_Up_Btq

easily the name range is called by:
=query(NAMERANGENAME,"select B where A='"&Y9&"'")

but if I want to call the range from another cell in the sheet:
=query(A1,"select B where A='"&Y9&"'")
I get an error. I have confirmed spelling.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, how about using `INDIRECT` as follows?

#### Modified formula:

```
=query(indirect(A1),"select B where A='"&Y9&"'")
```

- In this case, it supposes that the cell "A1" has the name of the named range which is `Jazz_It_Up_Btq`.

#### Reference:

- [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)